# "Job aborted due to stage failure" when using CreateDataFrame in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Following the instructions in this post (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#from-local-data-frames) I am creating a sparkdataframe using the following code:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "spark://master:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.cores.max="8", spark.executor.cores = "4"))
data(iris)
iris = createDataFrame(iris)
head(iris)
```

But the `head` function always leads to the below error. I get the same error when I try to run `dim` as well. I have also tried `as.DataFrame` instead of `createDataFrame`.  I have also tried restarting the kernel in my ipython notebook and restarting my spark session.

My understanding is that this is a pretty basic function of SparkR, so I am really at a loss for why it isn't working. For some reason, when I read my `SparkDataFrame` diectly from a data source using `read.jdbc` I have no problem. Also, I noticed that the number in the line of the error ":Task 0 in stage XXX.." increments by one each time it fails.

I also noticed that the error seems to be coming from the fact that the executors can't find the binary for `Rscript`, though I'm not sure why this would be happening only for SparkDataFrames that are created from local data.frames, and not from ones that are pulled from an external datasource.

Could someone please help me with this?

The full error stack trace is:

> Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...): “Use Sepal_Length instead of
>   Sepal.Length  as column name”Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...): “Use
>   Sepal_Width instead of Sepal.Width  as column name”Warning message in
>   FUN(X[[i]], ...): “Use Petal_Length instead of Petal.Length  as column
>   name”Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...): “Use Petal_Width instead of
>   Petal.Width  as column name”
>
> Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE,
>   className, methodName, ...): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 45.0 failed 4 times,
>   most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 45.0 (TID 3372, 10.0.0.5):
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": error=2, No such
>   file or directory     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner$.createRProcess(RRunner.scala:348)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner$.createRWorker(RRunner.scala:364)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:69)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.BaseRRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:49)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory   at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 24 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2183)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2182)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2187)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2545)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2187)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2163)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$.dfToCols(SQLUtils.scala:208)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils.dfToCols(SQLUtils.scala)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:38)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": error=2, No such
>   file or directory     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner$.createRProcess(RRunner.scala:348)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner$.createRWorker(RRunner.scala:364)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:69)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.BaseRRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:49)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>     at org.apache.spark Traceback:
>
> 1. head(charEx)
> 2. head(charEx)
> 3. .local(x, ...)
> 4. take(x, num)
> 5. take(x, num)
> 6. collect(limited)
> 7. collect(limited)
> 8. .local(x, ...)
> 9. callJStatic("org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils", "dfToCols",   .     x@sdf)
> 10. invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...)
> 11. stop(readString(conn))

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what went wrong with this -- sorry. I ended up switching to databricks in order to avoid these kinds of things. It is expensive though...

Answer (score 1):

This is how i understand it:

The reason `read.jdbc` works is because, on the nodes, `R` is not needed to perform the operation: the driver (where `R` runs) translates the command to `Spark` before it gets copied to, and executed, on the worker nodes.

The reason `createDataFrame` fails is because that gets copied to the worker nodes as an `R` command, hence the nodes need to have access to `Rscript`.

If you want to use `createDataFrame` to be able to play around with your data a bit, i suggest you use a local `Sparksession` (otherwise you have to copy `Rscript` to your worker nodes). If you need to pass your data through `R` to get it into `Spark` in the first place, you may want to reconsider (you're probably using `Spark` because you have oodles of data, and it's usually better to load and keep everything on the `Spark` side and just pull, for instance, aggregated chunks to `R` in-memory).